Fetch all products from Woocommerce using REST API
In wordpress site over 10,000 products are available.
I'm try to fetch all products from a WordPress site and  and implement a button click to load infinite new products. Currently, I'm facing an issue where existing products are duplicated each time I click the load button.
I've implemented the fetching logic using TypeScript and React Query. Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:
fetch-get-all-products.tsx
import { QueryOptionsType, Product } from "@framework/types";
import { useInfiniteQuery, QueryKey, QueryFunctionContext } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import WooCommerceRestApi from "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api";

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_SITE_URL,
  consumerKey: process.env.WC_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumerSecret: process.env.WC_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  version: "wc/v3",
});


type PaginatedProduct = {
  data: Product[];
  paginatorInfo: any;
};

const fetchProducts = async ({ pageParam = 1, limit = 100 }: { pageParam?: number; limit?: number }) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await WooCommerce.get(`products?per_page=${limit}&page=${pageParam}&status=publish`);
    const nextPageUrl = data.length > 0 ? `products?per_page=${limit}&page=${pageParam + 1}&status=publish` : null;
    return {
      data: data,
      paginatorInfo: {
        nextPageUrl,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Error fetching products");
  }
};

const useProductsQuery = (options: QueryOptionsType) => {
  return useInfiniteQuery<PaginatedProduct, Error>({
    queryKey: [options],
    queryFn: async ({
      pageParam = 1,
    }: QueryFunctionContext<QueryKey, unknown>) => {
      // You can use queryKey here if needed
      return fetchProducts({ pageParam: pageParam as number | undefined });
    },
    initialPageParam: 1, // Start from page 1
    getNextPageParam: ({ paginatorInfo }) => paginatorInfo.nextPageUrl,
  });
};

export { useProductsQuery, fetchProducts };

In Product-Grid to load button click to load new product
Product-Grid.tsx
import React from 'react';
import ProductCard from "@components/product/product-card";
import Button from "@components/ui/button";
import type { FC } from "react";
import { useProductsQuery } from "@framework/product/get-all-products";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import ProductFeedLoader from "@components/ui/loaders/product-feed-loader";
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import { Product } from "@framework/types";

interface ProductGridProps {
  className?: string;
}

export const ProductGrid: FC<ProductGridProps> = ({ className = "" }) => {
  const { query } = useRouter();
  const {
    isFetching: isLoading,
    isFetchingNextPage: loadingMore,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    data,
    error,
  } = useProductsQuery({  ...query });

  if (error) return <p>{error.message}</p>;

  const { t } = useTranslation("common");

  // Filter products based on selected price range
  let filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
  if (data?.pages) {
    filteredProducts = data.pages
      .map((page) => page?.data || [])
      .flat()
      .filter((product: Product) => {
        if (!query.price) return true; // If no price filter selected, show all products
        const [minPrice, maxPrice] = (query.price as string).split("-");
        const productPrice = parseFloat(product.price); // Assuming product price is a number
        return productPrice >= parseFloat(minPrice) && (maxPrice ? productPrice < parseFloat(maxPrice) : true);
      });
  }

  return (
    <>
      {filteredProducts.length === 0 && (
        <div className="py-4 text-red-500 font-medium text-sm md:text-sm">
         There is no product found for this search
        </div>
      )}
      <div
        className={`grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 2xl:grid-cols-5 gap-x-3 lg:gap-x-5 xl:gap-x-7 gap-y-3 xl:gap-y-5 2xl:gap-y-8 ${className}`}
      >
        {isLoading && !data ? (
          <ProductFeedLoader uniqueKey="search-product" />
        ) : (
          filteredProducts?.map((product: Product) => (
            <ProductCard
              key={`product--key${product.id}`}
              product={product}
              variant="grid"
              id={0}
            />
          ))
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="text-center pt-8 xl:pt-14">
        {hasNextPage && (
          <Button
            loading={loadingMore}
            disabled={loadingMore}
            onClick={() => fetchNextPage()}
            variant="slim"
          >
            {t("button-load-more")}
          </Button>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

The problem arises when I click the load button; it appears to fetch and render products repeatedly, including duplicates of existing ones.
I suspect the issue might be with how I handle pagination or the logic for checking existing products. Could someone review my code snippets and provide guidance on how to resolve this duplication issue?
Additionally, I'm also interested in ensuring the correctness of my code comments and variable names. Any suggestions.
